# refrigerator making weird noises

Tags: refrigerator

I have a rather old freezer\refrigerator unit in my house. Its cooling works perfectly, however ever since a few weeks ago, once every few hours when what I assume is the compressor starts operating, in addition to the normal static noise it makes, every few minutes it also makes one of the two following weird sounds: the first is a relatively soft sound of a liquid flowing through a tube, and the second is a very loud sound similar to a vibrating wind instrument. both sounds last for an average of 10 seconds at a time, and are coming from the upper part of the unit (the back of the freezer).

I am looking for ideas on what might cause these noises, the second one especially, and if it is possible for me to fix this without investing in new expensive parts.
(just to clarify, the unit does not have an ice maker)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good info about the ice maker, but even  so it's going to be hard to help you on this one without more info (make, model, picture). And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: sounds like an icemaker dumping ice cubes and filling up the tray with water ... maybe you did not notice it before ...  maybe you had the icemaker turned off and you had someone visiting who turned it on

Comment: So you have a noise but everything is working fine, other than a noise? 
The liquid flowing through the tube is probably Freon or the refrigerant, you may not have noticed before but is not unusual. As for the other noise I would guess your start cap is failing , and the compressor is having a hard time starting this becomes more common with older units. The cap is on the side of the compressor normally under a cover where the power enters the compressor. Make sure to unplug prior to open this cover. If it is the cap they can be found on line usually for ~20$